# Resize span4 - fit background image & set height of DIV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of squares that should fill a page grid. 3 columns (span4) per row.

I would like a background image to fill the span4 edge to edge, and as the browser is resized it will be squashed appropriately.

I would like the height of the span to match the background image's height. So when it goes to a lower width, the heigh proportionally decreases.

Essentially it is as if the image isn't in the background but just a responsive image. It needs to be background as I want to write text over the top of it.

Is this possible? What would be a good approach without having to manually set height values for each span & how do I get a background image to squash down?